# Select list is populated correctly but value not included in POST

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage that uses a `JavaScript` function to populate a second dropdown box when an item from a first dropdown box is picked. The function creates the second drop down changing this:

```
<td>
<form action="http://website/addToDepartment.php" method="post">
<div id="nondepartment">
</div>
</td>
```

to this:

```
<td>
<form action="http://website/addToDepartment.php" method="post">
<div id="nondepartment">
<select name="personName">
<option value="Bob" name="personName">Bob</option>
<option value="Jim" name="personName">Jim</option>
<option value="Tom" name="personName">Tom</option>
</select>
</div>
</td>
```

My problem is that when the form button is pressed it does not POST the *personName* value chosen from the created list. If I write exactly the same code manually, so the function is not called, then it works. If I use the function to create the list it doesn't (no string at all gets POSTED). Why might this be?

Comment: The option elements should not have a name property.

Comment: @Richard accept answer too, if problem solved.. thnks :)

Comment: I appreciate the help but it has not fixed it. It now does as you suggest but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a conflict with the `name` property. Remove the `name` property from all of the options;you only need it on the `select` element. Also, make sure (recommend using Firebug) that the markup you are giving above is literally what does get produced; I've had before where injecting elements aren't in the `<form>` tag as expected, depending on how it's used sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing your form tag. Probably there lies your issue.

The HTML generated content should work to POST your values. Probably because the FORM is not closed, the browser will close it for you on a spot you do not expect.

Also you only need a name attribute on your SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<td>
<form action="http://website/addToDepartment.php" method="post">
<div id="nondepartment">
</div>
    </form>
</td>

<td>
<form action="http://website/addToDepartment.php" method="post">
<div id="nondepartment">
<select name="personName">
<option value="Bob" >Bob</option>
<option value="Jim" >Jim</option>
<option value="Tom" >Tom</option>
</select>
</div>
    </form>
</td>
```